# How to get Map Pixels

Tags: jquery, openlayers-3

Here is code example of openlayers 3 to create a map -

```
<script>
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  })
});

var highlightStyleCache = {};

var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
  map: map,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '';
    if (!highlightStyleCache[text]) {
      highlightStyleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#f00',
          width: 1
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
          text: text,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#f00',
            width: 3
          })
        })
      })];
    }
    return highlightStyleCache[text];
  }
});

var highlight;
var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {

  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });

  var info = document.getElementById('info');
  if (feature) {
    info.innerHTML = feature.getId() + ': ' + feature.get('name');
  } else {
    info.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  }

  if (feature.get('name')=='Pakistan') {
    /*if (highlight) {
      featureOverlay.removeFeature(highlight);
    }*/
    if (feature) {
      featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);
    }
    highlight = feature;
  }

};

/*$(map.getViewport()).on('load', function(evt) {
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
});
*/
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
});

 </script>
```

I want to pass pixel to `displayFeatureInfo` without using `click event` i want to use `load` event instead - but its not working!

```
  map.on('load', function(evt) {
      displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
    });
```

OR

```
map.load(function(evt) {
          displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
        });
```

Comment: The map's load event does not call its listeners with an event object with a pixel. You have to ask yourself: with which pixel do you want to call your displayFeatureInfo function? The center of the map? A random pixel? Then you will have to provide that pixel, and not use evt.pixel.

Comment: @ahocevar i want to provide map pixel